# Unable to import in CoreNFC in swift project Xcode 9 beta

Tags: ios, ios11, xcode9-beta

I am unable to import `CoreNFC` in a swift project. Getting this error `No such module CoreNFC`.

[image]

I also added the framework to `Linked Frameworks and Libraries`.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [a post on the Apple Developer forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/232384#232384), you can only build for a real device or the Generic iOS device as there is no x86 version of CoreNFC.

Once you switch to one of these, you do not need to add CoreNFC to `Linked Frameworks and Libraries`, just @import it:

```
@import CoreNFC;
```