# iOS 11 Core NFC - No such module 'Core NFC'

Tags: ios, swift, core-nfc

I'm currently working on CoreNFC, and I've got an error:

I have included the CoreNFC framework into my app, but even then the error exists: No such module 'CoreNFC'

I ran the code from this official link https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/718/

Comment: did you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44386023/unable-to-import-in-corenfc-in-swift-project-xcode-9-beta

Comment: Also, it's **CoreNFC**, not **Core NFC** - there no space in it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to import in CoreNFC in swift project Xcode 9 beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44386023/unable-to-import-in-corenfc-in-swift-project-xcode-9-beta)

Comment: I haven't added space between Core and NFC. I ran the code from https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/718/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No such module 'Core NFC' error occurs while running the app in the simulator other than the device.

Hope this helps someone...

Answer (score 0):

1. Clean your *build folder* (i.e., <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>)
2. Rebuild your project.

It worked for me.